# NEventStore problem configuring SQL dialect

Tags: event-sourcing, neventstore

I am working on a prototype CQRS implementation and trying to use Jonathan Oliver's event store with MS SQL server:

```
 _store = Wireup.Init()
            .UsingSqlPersistence("EventStore")
                .InitializeDatabaseSchema()
            .UsingJsonSerialization()
            .Build();
```

I have a matching connection string defined in app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Business.Domain.Repository.Tests.Properties.Settings.EventStore"
        connectionString="Data Source=EventStore.sdf;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have tried variations of connection strings for SQL CE, local SQL, remote SQL server's and always get this error:

```
    System.NullReferenceException was caught
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=EventStore
  StackTrace:
       at EventStore.Persistence.SqlPersistence.SqlPersistenceFactory.GetDialect() in c:\Projects\Business\Proto1\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Persistence.SqlPersistence\SqlPersistenceFactory.cs:line 53
       at EventStore.Persistence.SqlPersistence.SqlPersistenceFactory.Build() in c:\Projects\Business\Proto1\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Persistence.SqlPersistence\SqlPersistenceFactory.cs:line 46
       at EventStore.SqlPersistenceWireup.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__1(NanoContainer c) in c:\Projects\Business\Proto1\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Wireup\SqlPersistenceWireup.cs:line 13
       at EventStore.ContainerRegistration.Resolve(NanoContainer container) in c:\Projects\Business\Proto1\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Wireup\NanoContainer.cs:line 66
       at EventStore.NanoContainer.Resolve[TService]() in c:\Projects\Business\Proto1\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Wireup\NanoContainer.cs:line 40
       at EventStore.PersistenceWireup.Build() in c:\Projects\Business\Proto1\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Wireup\PersistenceWireup.cs:line 47
```

Has anyone come across this before or have an idea what I am doing wrong?  I tried stepping through the source and still not sure why there is a null reference. 
-Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm updating some of the error handling now surrounding dialect detection.  You'll need to add a "providerName" to your connection string, e.g.:

```
 <add name="Business.Domain.Repository.Tests.Properties.Settings.EventStore"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"
  connectionString="Data Source=EventStore.sdf;" />
```

Having the providerName attribute in the connection configuration allows the EventStore to know which driver to use when connecting to your database instance.

Comment: I just updated the code to give a better error message: https://github.com/joliver/EventStore/commit/6b48e017b4b479e815a9b5021e442c7fca1fdf79

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it and the better error message should help anyone else who makes the same mistake.